# Can silverfish climb and produce silk?

Tags: entomology

I am equally disgusted and fascinated by the "Silverfish" (*Lepisma saccharina*) that we regularly find in our UK home. I tried searching for information on the internet but they seem poorly understood.

We only ever find them on the work surface in the kitchen when we switch on a light at night. They are presumably feeding off food residues - but they never seem to be found in the most obvious place, among the crumbs under the toaster.

When caught by the lights, they run for cover but never, ever climb. You would think them unable to climb at all but then how have they reached the work surface?

The other day there appeared a new twist; 2 "husks" hanging from silk threads between 2 containers, maybe 8cm from the surface. If they were caught and eaten by a spider, why did it take them to a rudimentary web when it (presumably) caught them on the surface? There was no sign of a spider around. The only other possibility I can see is that they somehow suspended THEMSELVES from the silk and this was a moulting behaviour. Thus they now CAN climb - and very well - and also produce silk!
Can anyone explain the mystery?

Comment: Hi. Is your question: "What is the function of silk in Silverfish?" (I didn't know they could produce silk).

Comment: @Remi.b -  I think POs title question should be "Can silverfish climb and produce silk?"

Comment: Modified question title, feel free to rollback if it doesn't match what you are trying to ask. Also, a photo of the aforementioned "husks" would be helpful.

Comment: You read my mind @MarchHo

Answer (score 2):

According to a paper by [Walker et al. (2013)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23578395) (found by googling "[silverfish + silk](https://www.google.se/search?q=silverfish+silk&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=wHARVZ_9L4j4ywP71oDYDA)", so not very hard to come by), silverfish can indeed produce silk. The paper also mentions that silverfish (Thysanura) and bristletails (Archaeognatha) use silk to transfer their sperm, and they also use it for "*...tactile cue during courtship (Sturm, 1956)*". [This](http://www.cals.ncsu.edu/course/ent425/library/compendium/thysanura.html) webpage (from NY State University) explains that male silverfish will deposit a spermatophore on a silk thread that is vertically suspended, and the spermatophore is later picked up by a female.

> **Abstract:**
>   Silks are semi-crystalline solids in which protein chains are associated by intermolecular hydrogen bonding within ordered crystallites, and by entanglement within unordered regions. By varying the type of protein secondary structure within crystallites and the overall degree of molecular order within fibers, arthropods produce fibers with a variety of physical properties suited to many purposes. We characterized silk produced as a tactile stimulus during mating by the grey silverfish (Ctenolepisma longicaudata) using Fourier transform infrared spectroscopy, polarized Raman spectroscopy, gel electrophoresis and amino acid analysis. Fibers were proteinaceous-the main component being a 220 kDa protein-and were rich in Gln/Glu, Leu, and Lys. The protein structure present was predominantly random coil, with a lesser amount of beta-structure. Silk fibers could readily be solubilized in aqueous solutions of a mild chaotrope, sodium dodecyl sulfate, indicating protein chains were not cross-linked by disulfide or other covalent bonds. We conclude that entanglement is the major mechanism by which these silk proteins cohere into a solid material. We propose silks used as short-term tactile cues are subject to less stringent requirements for molecular order relative to other silks, allowing the random coil structure to be favored as an adaptation promoting maximal entanglement and adhesion.

The linked paper contains several references that should be useful if you want to look deeper into how silverfish use silk.

From what I've seen, they don't use silk for climbing. Silverfish can usually climb rough surfaces, but not smooth surfaces, which is why they are often found trapped in sinks, bathtubs etc.

Comment: This species seems to be different to the one we have in the UK and is more an American variant according to Wikipedia. However, it seems strange that a species would develop silk glands simply for such an undefined function - even one related to reproduction.

Comment: @Lefty Since the paper seems to claim that the ability of produce silk covers the entire order of Thysanura (along with bristletails, spiders etc), it is unlikley to be specific to their particular study species. To use silk for courtship and sperm transfer is hardly "*undefined*", since reproduction is essential in the life history of a species.

Comment: No, these papers are more interested in the structure of the silk, not the lifestyle of the Silverfish. The only thing it does is to confirm that they do indeed produce silk for the purpose of reproduction - although to transfer sperm packets, not as a "tactile stimulus" in your extract. I'm interested in their reluctance to climb and whether the silk is used in the moulting process.

Comment: @Lefty in that case, please edit your question so the actual _question_ being asked is clearer.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me, just read the question text rather than the title.

Comment: @Lefty Yes, for tactile cues. Read the entire paper, if you are honestly interested in an answer:   "*Approaching the end
of the courtship ritual, which consists of antenna-tapping and
repeated responsive movements between male and female (Sturm,
1956,1987), male L. saccharina cover an area of the substratewith Y-
shaped networks of fibers and deposit a spermatophore nearby.
Detection of the Y-shaped tactile cues by the female induces a
sequence of behaviors that culminates in her uptake of the sper-
matophore (Sturm, 1956).*"

Comment: @fileunderwater I've never used pubmed and from what I can see, I can't just view this paper without signing-up in some way. If I'm wrong please correct me. Either way, my original question without all the chatter can be condensed into 4 parts: 1) What are they eating if breadcrumbs are not on the menu? 2) Can they climb? 3) Can they produce silk? 4) Do they suspend themselves from silk and moult? From what you've said so far, this paper appears to answer point 3) with "Yes".

Comment: @Lefty Sorry, forgot to mention that the paper is available for free [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236194911_Silverfish_silk_is_formed_by_entanglement_of_randomly_coiled_protein_chains) (view/download to the right). **1)** dead insects, starch (wallpaper glue), paper, fabric etc. **2)** Yes, but not on smooth surfaces, and not using silk from what I know. **3)** Yes (see above), **4)** I don't know about their molting behaviour, except they molt many times during their lifetime, and the paper linked above doesn't mention molting in relation to their silk.

Comment: Thanks @fileunderwater I'll have a read of it then. 1) The Wiki article mentions the same foodstuffs you've listed - none of which would appear to be present on my (tiled) work surface. Nonetheless they would appear to be able to thrive there somehow. 2) Bizarrely, most of the vertical surfaces are actually rough (wood) yet they never appear to climb them but 4) the objects they were hanging from were smooth porcelain containers.